# Java application export

Tags: java

Okay so I have been coding a game for a while now and I am hoping to release its alpha just one problem. I don't know how to export it and run it. Please note that all my code works fine. So when I export it I export it as a Runnable jar file once I do so I set it and have tried both exporting it as .jar and .exe. Once I exported it I tested it by clicking the resulting file but it doesn't open the application but rather it opens it in eclipse encoded. Please help I may just be an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try to launch it with:

```
java -jar yourrunnable.jar
```

If you plan to run on windows and you want a .exe file, try to check this SO question: [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)
or if you want to target a mac, you can have a check here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

Basically any platform you target you have some customization in order to achieve a seamless run. Anyway the most cross platform solution is the `Java -jar` way.

Comment: Okay so no offense but where do I put said java -jar yourrunnable.jar? Command prompt or .bat file?

Comment: @Azamp19 a bat file is a quite common solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with .jar files not opening on a double click. It turned out that I had two versions of Java installed (Java 6 and 7). Uninstalling Java 6 from Control Panel-> Uninstall a Program was what finally allowed .jar files to open on a double click without using the command window.

What is listed in right-click-> Open With ? Is some other program listed as the default program ? Is a Java Runtime listed ? If a Java Runtime is listed, you can open with it, and make it the default program to run with.

```
Right Click ->  Properties -> Change -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

For Java  8 use below

```
java.exe -jar myFile.jar
```